# understanding file encodings

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, latin1

in eclipse, I have a file where some place this is written:

```
onclick='obj1.help_open_new_window(fn1(), "/redir/url_name")'
```

and in eclipse Edit menu->set encoding, I see this:

[image]

Now I change the encoding to UTF-8 using the same dialog box and the text changes to:

```
onclick='obj1.help_open_new_window(fn1(),�"/redir/url_name")'
```

All I know is if this was not happening, then my website would be working fine. Why is this happening and what do I do to prevent this?

I do have some knowledge about encodings: [Ã‚ and nbsp mystery explained](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2008/01/a_and_nbsp_myst.html) [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.java.net/external?url=http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) but still I do not understand why this is happening. Feel free to go to byte level(how file is stored) just to explain it.

***UPDATE***: Here's what I understand: if the file is encoded in `latin-1` then every character is a byte and so is the . it should be `hex(32)`. now when I convert it to utf-8, it still remains `hex(32)` and that is definitely . this leads me to believe that in latin-1,  is not `hex(32)` but a combination of two bytes. How is that possible?

Comment: If you can, open the file with a hex editor to find out what bytes actually are stored in the file at that point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character you have between the comma and the quote appear sto not be a normal space but some other whitespace character, probably the famous [U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm). Since the file is encoded in latin1, the character is stored on disk as the byte `\xA0`, which does not form a valid character in UTF-8. This means that if you reload the file in your editor using UTF-8 you will see the universal replacement character `�` in its stead. (The proper UTF-8 encoding of no-break space would be `\xC2\xA0`.)

To get rid of the problem replace the no-break space with a normal space (U+0020). There is no reason why you should use a no-break space in this context, i.e. in program text.

Comment: Okay but why would eclipse insert a `U+00A0` instead of `U+0020` on pressing a spacebar?

Comment: Maybe someone copied and pasted this code from a web page that used a no-break space. Or maybe someone accidentally typed in a no-break space: some people have a configuration that inserts a no-break space when they type Shift+Space for example. This often leads to needless no-break spaces in files they edit.